# Load Embedded Resources as Images in MAUI

Tags: android, maui

I created a simple program with MAUI to load 2 images, specified as Embedded Resources.
This is the MainPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Surprise.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="550"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="ImageContainer"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 HeightRequest="500"
                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  HeightRequest="40">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Button Text="Image1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Clicked="OnImage1ButtonClicked" />
                
                <Button Text="Image2"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Clicked="OnImage2ButtonClicked" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

and this is its code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly Image _image1;
    private readonly Image _image2;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _image1 = new Image()
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Surprise.Resources.Images.image1.jpeg"),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HeightRequest = 500
        };

        _image2 = new Image()
        {
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Surprise.Resources.Images.image2.jpg"),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HeightRequest = 500
        };
    }

    private void OnImage1ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageContainer.Children.Clear();
        ImageContainer.Children.Add(_image1);
    }

    private void OnImage2ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageContainer.Children.Clear();
        ImageContainer.Children.Add(_image2);
    }
}
```

On Windows it works correctly.
On Android sometimes the images are loaded in wrong order or even the same image is loaded when I press each button.
Is it a MAUI bug or I'm missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the MauiImage build action and then just using the name of the file as shown here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-a-local-image, Also i think the embedded resource thing could be a bug

Comment: Using the MauiImage build action it works.
Add your suggestion as an answer, so I can select it as the right one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are some changes that were made with Maui projects, we now have Maui-specific build actions that you can use to specify to your project/solution what the type of a certain file is.

In your Scenario, you should use the `MauiImage` build action and then just use the name of the file as shown here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-a-local-image should be enough to fix your issue