# MAUI Image as embedded resouce

Tags: image, maui

I am creating a MAUI project that uses graphic components (buttons) defined in an external DLL.
The images of these buttons are resources embedded in the external DLL that I load in this way:

```
ImageSource.FromResource (Instance.LOCAL_ASSEMBLY_IMAGEPATH + filename, Instance.LOCAL_ASSEMBLY);
```

When I run on windows the images are correct, when I run on android the images are randomly placed ...
This is only a display issue because the button instance is right.

Windows example
[image]

Android example
[image]

XAML top bar

```
 <Shell.TitleView>

        <Grid x:Name="ShellViewObject" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0" Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

Button creation as follows

```
 BadgeButton vo = new SimpleControls.BadgeButton();
            vo.StyleId = name;
            vo.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0); 
            vo.Margin   = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            vo.ImageSize = 40;
            vo.BadgeImageText = img;
            vo.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
            vo.Clicked += CALLING_TOP_BAR_BUTTON_CLICK;
            vo.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            return vo;
```

Badge button XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSY.SimpleControls.BadgeButton" Padding="0" Margin="0">
    <Grid Padding="0" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image  x:Name="BadgeIconImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Margin="3" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                       />
        <Frame x:Name="BadgeFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="8"
                   Padding="0" HasShadow="False"  BorderColor="Transparent"
                   VerticalOptions="Fill"   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="35">
            <Label x:Name="BadgeTextLabel" FontSize="3"  HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: you need to show the XAML or code for the layout

Comment: @Jason XAML added.

Comment: which one of those icons is `BadgeButton`?  Where are the other two created?   And you don't show how anything is placed in the layout container

Comment: All of them are BadgeButtons , they are created in code behind and added to the ShellViewObject Grid using  grid.add(view, col,row)

Comment: @d.mercanti did you try to use horizontalStackLayout instead of grid? with that layout everytime you add a new item it would be right to the previous one. And the only thing i see on your code it's that you don't define the grid.colum of each BadgeButton, and if you don't define that, it would have a random order, depending on wich you insert first!

Comment: @LeandroToloza i'm adding the BadgeButtons using Grid.add (view,col,row) . Horizontal stacklaout can't overlap image.

Comment: I wrote a simple maui demo about grid, and it running on android without random placement. Can you provide some of your code for adding the BadgeButtons using Grid.add (view,col,row)?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT try with this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CCy64dAu2lo52RDwe1fJ-mGF-qZohGT0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @d.mercanti I can't open the link you provided, you can edit the question to add relevant code or upload the demo on GitHub.

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT  here https://github.com/merco/MauiBadgeButton

Comment: same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73612079/load-embedded-resources-as-images-in-maui

Comment: @d.mercanti Did the answer to this issue work for you?

Comment: @Dongzhi Wang-MSFT Yes, Using the MauiImage build action it works